# How to change the action of a h: form?

Tags: jsf, action

I need to change the action of a , because I'm loading with JQuery load (), the JSF pages within a div, but as I press the save button, I fully recharged page.

Home.jsf

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//ES"
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
              xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"  lang="es"><!--<![endif]-->
        <f:view contentType="text/html">
            <h:head>
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
                <title>Sistema de Seguimientos de Ciclos de Calidad</title>
                <meta name="description" content=""/>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

                <!-- Libreria jQuery -->
                <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <!-- Acción sobre el botón con id=boton y actualizamos el div con id=capa -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function cargar(desde)
                    {
                        $("#frame").load(desde);
                    }
                </script>


            </h:head>
    <h:body link="#000033">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#" onclick="cargar('/sistema.ciclos.calidad/modulos/input/dpu.jsf')">Desafios Propios de la Unidad</a></li>

          </ul>
          <div id="frame" >

          </div>
</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

dpu.jsf   on this page when I press save, I reload the entire page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title></title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="formulario">
    <h2>Meta</h2>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel for="meta">Meta</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputTextarea id="meta" readonly="true" cols="30" rows="20" value="#{cmiDetalle.cmi.meta}"></h:inputTextarea>
        <h:outputLabel for="nivel_logro">Nivel de Logro</h:outputLabel>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="nivel_logro" value="#{cmiDetalle.cmi.nivelLogro}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{util.nivelLogro}" var="nivel" itemLabel="#{nivel}" itemValue="#{nivel}"></f:selectItems>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:commandButton actionListener="#{cmiDetalle.updateCMI()}" value="Guardar"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

to view the source code of the page, the generated form has an action that I did not put.

```
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="post" action="/sistema.ciclos.calidad/modulos/input/cnaDetalle.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="formulario" value="formulario">

        <h2>Criterio</h2><table>
<label for="formulario:criterio">
Citerio</label><textarea id="formulario:criterio" name="formulario:criterio" cols="20" rows="10" readonly="readonly">1-Revisión y validación del perfil a lo menos una vez al año</textarea><label for="formulario:nivel_logro">
Nivel de Logro</label>
<select id="formulario:nivel_logro" name="formulario:nivel_logro" size="1"> <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="25" selected="selected">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="75">75</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="formulario:j_idt14" value="Actualizar"><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="6763485926333611189:-3375404461728497190" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Comment: If you're going to use another action then do not use `<h:form>` at all, use a plain `<form>`.

Comment: I already tried with `<form>` does not work, just reload the whole page.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that you should use plain HTML components and no JSF for this job.

Comment: just solved the problem by using
`String url="/sistema.ciclos.calidad/home.jsf"; 
        FacesContext fc=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        try {
            fc.getExternalContext().redirect(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }`